# Define Data Mode in mkfs.ext4 command

Tags: linux, mount, ext4, mkfs

Is there an option to define the default *data mode* when using mkfs?

The command `mkfs -t ext4 /dev/sdc1` format a partition as ext4 with default journal mode *data=ordered*.
I could set the *data=journal* with the command `tune2fs -o journal_data /dev/sdc1`.

Is there any option in mkfs to create the journal *data=journal* directly?

Answer (score 2):

I don’t think there’s a command-line option to set default mount options at `mke2fs` time, but they can be set in `mke2fs.conf`:

```
[defaults]
        default_mntopts = journal_data
```

(or in a more appropriate section if you only want this for specific profiles).

Comment: There _should_ really be a mke2fs "-J data=journal" option, or at least "-E mount_opts='data=journal'" (or 'journal_data' to match tune2fs), but it doesn't appear any of those options exist.  That seems like a gap, and should probably be politely requested on the linux-ext4 mailing list, or even better submitted as a patch.

Comment: Hi thanks for the Hint to the configuration file. For the moment, this solution works for me... Probably the integration in mke2fs could help for better usage directly on the command line. I will check the idea with the mailing list.